# Avalonia MVVM data templates

Tags: c#, mvvm

Hey I'm doing a Windows App with Avalonia using MVVM.
I have a navigation viewmodel which holds the current view.It looks like this:

```
   public class NavigationVM : ViewModelBase
   {
       public NavigationVM()
       {
           //first time created assigns the currentvm to loginvm
           CurrentVM = new LoginVM(this);
       
       }

       private ViewModelBase? currentvm;
       public ViewModelBase CurrentVM
       {
           get => currentvm!;
           set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref currentvm, value);
       }
   }
```

In MainWindow.xaml I bind its content to CurrentVM (yes, I set the datacontext to the navigation viewmodel).

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:MusicPlayer.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="MusicPlayer.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="MusicPlayer"
        x:CompileBindings="True"
        x:DataType="vm:NavigationVM"
        Content="{Binding CurrentVM}"
        >
    <Window.DataTemplates>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginVM}">
            <views:LoginView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.DataTemplates>
                       
</Window>
```

I am aware that a viewmodel can't be visually shown so I tried using data templates. LoginView is just a view with a label. But it shows me this error:

[image: error]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not about Avalonia .... it tells you that the startup project is not of Type EXE it's a class library .... you have multiple project in the solution, and you start the wrong one .... right-click On the EXE project and choose `Set as startup project` as following

[image: Set project as startup project in Visual Studio]

desktop project which output `winexe` As startup project

[image: show the final look]